# what does <id underscore number> mean in SQL indexing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to improve my understanding of SQL syntax by reading schemas and SQL files. The following code snippet is taken from a **very large raw file** on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases/master/bible-mysql.sql).

**My question:** In the unique key and in the indexing section of the CREATE TABLE block `id` is followed by an underscore and a numeral. What does the *underscore numeral* mean?

I can think of several possibilities, but none make sense given the data (especially in reference to the UNIQUE KEY.)

```
KEY `id_2` (`id`)
```

- That `id_2` is similar to `id[1]` in other languages so that the line reads

  - an index of digit two of the id field.
- It is an index of the first two digits of the id field.
- It is an index of the last two digits of the id field.

Again, none of these seem to make sense when comparing to `` UNIQUE KEY `id_3` (`id`) ``.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_asv` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `t` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_3` (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  KEY `id_4` (`id`),
  KEY `id_5` (`id`),
  KEY `id_6` (`id`),
  KEY `id_7` (`id`),
  KEY `id_8` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `t_asv`
--

INSERT INTO `t_asv` (`id`, `b`, `c`, `v`, `t`) VALUES
(01001001, 1, 1, 1, 'In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.'),
(01001002, 1, 1, 2, 'And the earth was waste and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep: and the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.'),
(01001003, 1, 1, 3, 'And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.')
```

Comment: Isn't it just the index name? Doesn't really mean anything, not sure why it has duplicate indexes either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` definition in a table creates an index.  The name following the key is the name of an index.  So:

```
key id_1 (id)
```

creates an index called "id_1" on key.  The "_1" doesn't mean anything.  It is part of the name of the index.

It would be equivalent to:

```
create index id_1 on t_asv(id);
```

You *can* do this multiple times, as in your example.  As far as I know, there is absolutely no reason to have multiple indexes with the same keys -- unless you want to demonstrate the wrong thing to do when creating a table.

Comment: probably You don't understand question

Comment: @JacekCz . . . If you have a different understanding you should answer the question.

Comment: Look @charleh comment. Underscore means nothing,

Comment: @JacekCz . . . This answer precedes that comment by two minutes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That makes sense. It's just the INDEX name and has nothing to do with *lowercase* index (digit). They could just as easily been named `foo` and then `foo97`, `foo98`, `foo99` etc.  I'm guessing that the duplication is for some advanced querying purposes.